# Trying to clean up (fix) vob file time code in order to point FFMPEG to in and out points

Tags: video, ffmpeg

*Background:* 15 years ago I created a DVD with a Ulead video editing software. Unfortunately, I have lost the original footage files, so as I now like to extract some clips from the videos, I have to extract from the vob files.

Using VLC media player I see that the time stamps are jumping randomly back and forth even within a single vob. Trying to extract using FFMPEG doesn't really work: A playable file is created, but I cannot properly control which parts of the original vob files I get into the output file. I guess this is probably because of the faulty time stamps. Hence...

**The question: Is there any way to re-mux/clean the vobs or otherwise create files without time stamp issues?**

BTW, trying to take 60 sec from one file and merge with 60 sec from another file I am using "FFMPEG -f concat -i list.txt ..." with a list.txt looking like this:

```
file Vts_01_3.vob
inpoint 212.0
outpoint 272.0
file Vts_01_4.vob
inpoint 0.0
outpoint 60.0
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Hmmm... was looking for a FFMPEG solution, but AviDemux did the job.

Answer (score 1):

As I got no suggestions for a FFMPEG solution is searched for other ways, and found one: AviDemux does the job!

AviDemux didn't complain at all about the time stamps - it seems AviDemux just reads/plays the vob-file(s) assuming each file is a continuous clip. AviDemux even suggests to load associated vob-files that (from the names) appear to be related to the one that one tries to open; and it works.

Selecting start and stop for the clip to be exported is very intuitive and in order to avoid a transcoding of the video, I just selected the 'copy' option in video output. The output container can also be chosen from a number of different options. For my purpose the 'Mpeg TS Muxer (ff)" worked. Expert of the marked clip is then executed via 'Save' in the File menu.

I guess "Handbrake" could also have been a solution, but I didn't investigate further.